# Codeigniter mysql query joining 2 values across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Although I can get the joins to work, it doesn't return the lowest deal possible. The result should be lowest handset price possible with the lowest monthly cost. Currently I can get the lowest handset price, but not with the lowest monthly cost and similarly lowest monthly cost but not with the lowest priced handset.

I have 3 tables DEALS, TARIFFS and HANDSETS. When a customer comes to a manufacturer product listing page, it loads all products related to that manufacturer (in most instances around 40 products). What I would like is it to load the cheapest deal available for each product. Tariff table has over 4000 records. Handset table has over 3000 records. Deals table has over 1 million records.

There is a representation of the the 3 tables below with relevant columns:

```
                  Handset Table
          ==================================
                  id    |    manufacturer_id
          -----------------------------------
                 100              1


                   Deals Table
==================================================
 tariff_id    |    handset_id    |    handset_cost
--------------------------------------------------
     15             100              44.99
     20             100             114.99


                 Tariffs Table
          ==============================
                 id    |    monthly_cost
          ------------------------------
                15           12.50
                20            7.50
```

This is the query

```
$this->db->select('h.name, t.monthly_cost, d.handset_cost');
        $this->db->from('aff_deals d');
        $this->db->join('aff_tariffs t', 't.id = d.tariff_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('aff_handsets h', 'h.id = d.handset_id', 'inner');

        if (isset($manuid)) {
            $this->db->where('h.manufacturer_id', $manuid);
        }

        $this->db->order_by('d.handset_cost ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('t.monthly_cost ASC');

        $this->db->group_by('h.name');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
```

Unfortunately this returns handset cost of £114.99 and monthly cost of £7.50, when I need £44.99 and £12.50. The example above is a simple snap shot. I have tried MIN(d.handset_cost), sub-queries but cannot get the desired results. Somehow I need to be able to get the lowest price handsets, even if it's 0.00 (FREE), with its equivalent monthly cost. Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

According to your query you are misusing Mysql's [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) extension without having any aggregate function this will lead your query to return indeterminate results for columns which are absent in group by taking your query as an example,columns `t.monthly_cost, d.handset_cost` values are indeterminate if you are specific to pick minimum row from deals table per handset then you can use below query

```
SELECT h.name,
t.monthly_cost,
d.handset_cost
FROM aff_deals d
INNER JOIN (SELECT handset_id,MIN(handset_cost) handset_cost 
            FROM aff_deals 
        GROUP BY handset_id) dd
      ON d.handset_id = dd.handset_id AND d.handset_cost = dd.handset_cost
INNER JOIN aff_tariffs t ON t.id = d.tariff_id
INNER JOIN aff_handsets h ON h.id = d.handset_id
WHERE h.manufacturer_id =1
ORDER BY d.handset_cost ASC,t.monthly_cost ASC
```

### [`See Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d767/4)

For active record query it will difficult to replicate above (subselect) query bu you  can directly run this query through `$this->db->query('your query')`

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to get back, I have tried your solution and it does work, however with the number of deals available it times out, is there any other way you can think of, should I consider looking at the schema.